# Annualizing quarterly dividends reported over several quarters

Tags: r, quantmod

I have a quarterly dividend payment history for a hypothetical company over the past five years. Here is the reproducible code:

```
Date<-as.Date(c("2013-11-01", "2014-02-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-08-01", "2014-11-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-08-01", "2015-11-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-08-01", "2016-11-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-11-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-08-01"))
Dividend<-c(0.08, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.00, 0.11, 0.11, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.00, 0.16, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)
data.frame(Date,Dividend)
```

with the below output:

```
         Date Dividend
1  2013-11-01     0.08
2  2014-02-01     0.10
3  2014-05-01     0.10
4  2014-08-01     0.10
5  2014-11-01     0.10
6  2015-02-01     0.11
7  2015-05-01     0.00
8  2015-08-01     0.11
9  2015-11-01     0.11
10 2016-02-01     0.13
11 2016-05-01     0.13
12 2016-08-01     0.13
13 2016-11-01     0.13
14 2017-02-01     0.14
15 2017-05-01     0.14
16 2017-08-01     0.00
17 2017-11-01     0.16
18 2018-02-01     0.15
19 2018-05-01     0.15
20 2018-08-01     0.15
```

My question is how to transform this into the output that would show dividends paid for each COMPLETE year, ignoring the first and last years if they are incomplete (as in this case, 2013 and 2018) and not assuming that the yearly dividend always equals quarterly dividend x 4 (in my example the years 2015 and 2017 don't have same amount of quarterly dividends).

So the output would look something like this:

```
Date    Dividend
2014    0.40
2015    0.33
2016    0.52
2017    0.44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define incomplete? Either you know the company has 4 div payments a year or 2 or 1 (or 12). Based on your reasoning none of other answers are correct, because they just assume that the first and last year should not be taken into account, but what happens in november 2018 when the fourth payment is made?

Since you are using quantmod, the data should be in xts form. Using `apply.yearly` will roll up the data to yearly rows, using the last available date of eacht year in the dataset. I use a the FUN part of the function to return 2 columns, 1 with the rolled up dividends and 1 with the number of dividends payed in the year. Since companies tend to have structured dividend payments (1, 2, 4 or 12), you can use the max number of div payments made to filter out the years that don't comply to this.

This might fail when you have something like special dividends that are not paid every year. Also the start of paying dividends doesn't always match up to the rules. Microsoft started paying dividends in 2013 and that were only 2 payments, after that quarterly payments were made.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2013-11-01", "2014-02-01", "2014-05-01", "2014-08-01", "2014-11-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-05-01", "2015-08-01", "2015-11-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-05-01", "2016-08-01", "2016-11-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-11-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-08-01")),
                  Dividend = c(0.08, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.10, 0.11, 0.00, 0.11, 0.11, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 0.00, 0.16, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15))

# data in xts form since quantmod is being used.
my_xts <- xts(df1$Dividend, order.by = df1$Date)

annual_data <- apply.yearly(my_xts, function(x) as.matrix(data.frame(sum(x), length(x)))  )
names(annual_data) <- c("total_divs", "no_divs")

# filter data to include only maximum dividens
annual_data[annual_data$no_divs == max(annual_data$no_divs)]

           total_divs no_divs
2014-11-01       0.40       4
2015-11-01       0.33       4
2016-11-01       0.52       4
2017-11-01       0.44       4
```

Comment: your reasoning is right, I only want to remove the first and/or last years if they have incomplete quarters (<4 per year). Special dividends should not be a problem because in this case there are still 4 or >4 dividend payments per year.

Answer (score 1):

We can remove the maximum and minimum `year` from the dataframe and then group by `year` and do the sum.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  filter(year(Date) != min(year(Date)) & year(Date) != max(year(Date))) %>%
  group_by(year = year(Date)) %>%
  summarise(Dividend = sum(Dividend))

#   year Dividend
#  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1  2014     0.4 
#2  2015     0.33
#3  2016     0.52
#4  2017     0.44
```

---

It's base R equivalent would be

```
df$Year <- as.numeric(format(df$Date, "%Y"))
aggregate(Dividend~Year, df[with(df, Year != min(Year) & Year != max(Year)), ],sum)

#  Year Dividend
#1 2014     0.40
#2 2015     0.33
#3 2016     0.52
#4 2017     0.44
```

Comment: that works too, but one caveat is that I only want to remove the first and/or last years if they have incomplete quarters. If they have dividends for all four quarters, I would like to keep them. In other words, they don't always have to be removed

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table` you can try

```
df<-data.frame(Date,Dividend)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(TotDiv=sum(Dividend)),
          by=year(Date), ][-c(which.min(year),which.max(year))]
   year TotDiv
1: 2014   0.40
2: 2015   0.33
3: 2016   0.52
4: 2017   0.44
```

Comment: I only want to remove the first or last years if they have incomplete quarters. If they have dividends for all four quarters, I would like to keep them.